# Android: C2DM Changing registration_id without notification?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

So I have a situation which I didn't think would happen based on my understanding of the registration My understanding:

Phone Registers with google gets registration_id, send registration_id to the server, use registration_id when sending out push notifications. If registration_id is updated by google, they will send a new registration broadcast.

However, I have case where a phone was registered, and was successfully receiving push notifications, but than one day the server goes to send a push notification to the phone and I get a error "NotRegistered" which would suggest the registration_id refreshed but did not get propagated through the system properly, whether it be on the phone side or the server side.

My question is has anyone else hand issues like this? What is the best approach to making sure this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) documentation:

> Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your application with the understanding that the `REGISTRATION` Intent may be called multiple times. Your application needs to be able to respond accordingly.